# Does the iPhone have an unencrytped boot partition?

Tags: iphone, startup, encryption

I'm trying to understand how the iPhone (and any other device) accomplishes its full-disk-encryption. When I have experimented with this on a Linux machine, when I encrypted the disk with LUKS partition, I had to leave the boot partition unencrypted so that the encryption related data could load to then prompt me with a password input to decrypt the drive, and following that, load the rest of the OS, as usual; however, on an iPhone, for example, the device boots directly to what looks like an OS login screen. How is it able to accomplish this? Is it storing a lightweight login program independent of the OS to initially decrypt the drive before then bootstrapping to the rest of the OS? I assume that its not actually part of the OS as this should not be possible if the device is using full disk encryption.

Comment: At the absolute minimum the bootloader code is either unencrypted, or is encrypted with a key that is available to the 1st stage bootloader that is embedded in the ARM processor core. I know from experience that ARM processors can and do often have some tiny amount of inbuilt program area that contains an initial bootloader and that code can essentially "go hunting" for locations to boot from, it's not too far fetched for it to have access to a key which can decrypt and launch the next boot stage. Not an actual answer as I'm not familiar with Apple platforms.

Comment: Have you read  the Apple Platform Security guide https://help.apple.com/pdf/security/en_AU/apple-platform-security-guide-x.pdf particularly with reference to Secure Enclave and the boot process (much the same on all recent Apple devices).